# Can't install Poetry in Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image due to setuptools error

Tags: python, docker, pip, setuptools, python-poetry

I'm trying to build the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt install -y python3.11 python3.11-distutils && \
    curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11 && \
    python3.11 -m pip install poetry==1.2.2
```

However, it fails to install `poetry` with the following error message:

```
Collecting msgpack>=0.5.2
  Downloading msgpack-1.0.4.tar.gz (128 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 128.1/128.1 kB 15.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

If I replace the install command for Poetry at the end and replace it with `python3.11 -m pip list` then the output clearly shows `setuptools` being installed:

```
Package             Version
------------------- -----------
...
setuptools          67.2.0
...
```

I can also `import setuptools` without problems when I open a Python interpreter. What is going on?

*Note that I'm unable to use a newer Ubuntu version or `pythonX.Y` image due to other requirements.*

Comment: Can I recommend instead of `curl get-pip.py | python3.11` try `python3.11 -m ensurepip && pip install --upgrade pip` ?

Comment: Also, don't install poetry into the global Python environment. See poetry docs on how to give poetry its own venv when doing a "manual install". Otherwise, use the official poetry install script.

Comment: @Kache I used the official Poetry install script and it works now, thanks!

Comment: @phd It didn't make a difference for me, but is there an advantage to that method? It requires me to install python3.11-full to have the ensurepip module.

Comment: @AlexanderOvervoorde Well, not much. Next try: `apt install -y python3.11-setuptools`

Comment: Cool, I'll submit it as an answer, then!

Comment: @phd That package doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't install poetry into the global Python environment (nor into your project venv), or it'll influence package compatibility within your project/system dependencies.

See poetry docs on how to give poetry its own venv when doing a "manual install". Otherwise, use the official poetry install script which does that for you.